# Geoserver JSON to Tabulator

Tags: javascript, json, geoserver, tabulator

I am working on OpenLayers and Geoserver.
When a user click a feature, I have an already created tabulator table to fetch feature info data.
My problem is that I need to convert the html response from Geoserver to JSON. How can I do that?

This is the response from Geoserver

```
<table class="featureInfo">
  <caption class="featureInfo">l1Data</caption>
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>sensor</th>
    <th>timestamp</th>
    <th>reliability</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>16021</td>
    <td>Basic</td>
    <td>Sep 18, 2020 12:05:02 PM</td>
    <td>0.929717403858748</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

the Tabulator has been set as:

```
table = new Tabulator("#eventtable", {
    //height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    columns:[
    {title:"ID", field:"id", visible:false},
    {title:"Sensor", field:"sensor", sorter:"string"},
    {title:"Last Detection", field:"timestamp", sorter:"date"},
    {title:"Reliability", field:"reliability", sorter:"number"},
    ],
  });
```

EDITED
I found that I can have an application/json response, but I can not put in Tabulator. The code on map click:

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var url = wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
      { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json' });
    if (url) {
      fetch(url)

        .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
        .then(function (html) {
          var test1 = JSON.parse(html);
          var test2 = test1.features[0].properties;
          table.setData(test2);
        });
    }
  });
```

The error is:

```
tabulator.min.js:2 Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type 
Expecting: array 
Received:  object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to work out how to convert it, simply ask GeoServer to return you the information as JSON. You can do that by setting the `info_format` parameter to `application/json`. The [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) gives full details of all the possible parameters and formats that can be used to control the response.

Comment: You are right. I already find how can I get application/json. But now I face another problem that tabulator need array not an object

Comment: the take the array of features from the object

Comment: have a look at the `ajaxResponse` callback it allows you to alter the data from the response before Tabulator ingests it. [Here is the example code](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/data#ajax-alter)